# Code, data, heap and stack layout without Segments in x64 long mode

Tags: 64-bit, x86-64, memory-segmentation

All right, it is clear that segmentation is not used in x64 long mode anymore.

But how we can use the stack... all references were based on the stack register or how we use variables in the data segment if all segment registers have 0 values.

I have problems joining the classical process layout in a world without segments.

Comment: The classical process layout already used the flat model, that's *why* segmentation has been downgraded in x86-64. The stack is accessed with both `ss` (mostly implicitly) and `ds` so we already had `ss`=`ds`. To fully exploit the 32-bit address space we also had `ds.limit = cs.limit = 4GiB` thus forcing the bases to 0. Long story short: all segments start at 0 and were 4GiB. This was extended seamlessly to the 48/64-bit address space of x86-64.

Comment: I haven't said it but the x86-64 segmentation forces the bases to 0 (but for `gs` and `fs`) and the limits to the max value. Maybe it the "there is no segmentation" that confused you.

Answer (score 1):

All references are still based on the segment registers, but the segment base is forced to 0 (except for FS and GS) and the segment limit is forced to 2<sup>64</sup> - 1.